# Centering an element in a div, when particles.js library is appending a canvas to same element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering, particles.js

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out the CSS for this. I am trying to center `section.title-block` inside of `div#particles`. Right now it is going to the left side of the page.

I can only assume the problem is caused by particles.js library appending the `<canvas>` to my HTML? I tried to position absolute the `div#particles` as well as the `canvas`, but this causes the background effect to lose its mouse over effect.

Here is a fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/Kaleid/yqhkwc93/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it

```
section.title-block {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wfxdmy1g/1/)